# using regex to split TM symbol from string?

Tags: python, regex, superscript

As the title states, I am trying to use regex to split the trademark ™ symbol from a string. I am looking for two possible patterns:

1. string™  --> expected result: string ™

or

2. string™2 --> expected result: string ™ 2

I came up with the below pattern to check whether a string contains either potential option:

```
pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+[™]([0-9])?$"
```

Is there any way to add some functionality to split it to end up with the expected results mentioned above?

Comment: Is `re.split('(™)','string™2')` -> `['string', '™', '2']` what you are looking for?

Comment: @MarkTolonen the problem I had with this approach is that if you have a full sentence then it just groups all text before and then after the tm symbol

like 'test test string™9 test test test' -> ['test test string', '™', '9 test test test']

I would need 'test test string ™ 9 test test test' as the output

Comment: That's new information that should be added to the question itself.  It's also not clear if you want a `list` result or a `str` result with spaces around the ™.  Be precise with inputs and outputs if you want a precise answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with `re.sub` in two steps. First add space from the left side where necessary and then from the right side:

```py
import re

s = """\
string™
string™2
string©2
test test string™9 test test test"""


s = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z0-9])([™©])", r"\1 \2", s)
s = re.sub(r"([™©])([0-9])", r"\1 \2", s)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
string ™
string ™ 2
string © 2
test test string ™ 9 test test test
```

Comment: is it possible to add any additional symbols to this? like if I had to also add a © at some point, can it be included?

Comment: cool thanks so much! I'm new to regex so this is a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

`re.split` will do the job, just give us all the information in the question.

Below uses a list comprehension to remove the splits caused by spaces and the extra empty string split when TM is at the end of the string:

```py
import re

trials = 'string™', 'string™2', 'test test string™9 test test test'

for trial in trials:
    result = [x for x in re.split(' |(™)', trial) if x]
    print(f'{result!r} {" ".join(result)!r}')
```

Output:

```
['string', '™'] 'string ™'
['string', '™', '2'] 'string ™ 2'
['test', 'test', 'string', '™', '9', 'test', 'test', 'test'] 'test test string ™ 9 test test test'
```